# All applications crashes on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, crash, system-restore

I rebooted my computer and I found that chrome (browser) will not open anymore. I noticed my audio doesn't work anymore either. If I start any other application like skype, IE and even file explorer they all seem to crash sooner or later.

All the apps ends up with "xyz has stopped working" dialog.

I tried [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/multiple-programs-keep-crashingwindows-7-64-bit/76e99298-3fea-4cfa-adfc-9c0dc6f9fd81?auth=1) which talks of clean boot via msconfig but that didn't help either. The only time my computer works if I go to 'boot' tab in msconfig and select 'safe boot' with network selected. Than I can reboot and my chrome or any other application works.

It seems like some service or app is messing up the system? I uninstalled everything I installed recently (last installs were few days back even though computer was running fine till today).

How can I get my system back to work?

**Update**

I also tried running sfc/scannow on windows command prompt (started with admin privileges) but no luck.

This might be clue and something weird I noticed is when I start an application and look in task manager, it often starts two instances, sometime three. For example I start chrome, two instances popups up in task manager.

When I start spotify, three instances pops up (under process column) than it becomes two, than three again and fnally back to two. Kind of weird.

Comment: Try going into Safe Mode and see if you can identify which application causing havoc? Maybe some recently installed applications? Accidentally set .exe to be opened by Adobe Reader (instead of running normally).. lots of things could cause this..  can you still get to Safe mode at all?

Comment: Can you list all the programs installed on your machine? Have you tried looking into task manager and see what app consumes the most processing power?

Comment: @Darius Yes I can reboot in safe mode and chrome works fine there. I have installed any application that was installed in last few days.

Comment: @alljamin No application consumes even 2% CPU time, system is idle. I do hear 'disk noise' though like its busy reading something. The fact that I have stopped ALL non microsoft services and all startup apps through MS config and still apps crashes is a bit strange, like its none of those apps!?